# Unity3d vs Flash vs Corona

Tags: unity3d, android, flash, iphone

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы узнать, что посоветуете для разработки игр и приложений для iphone/android, для разработчика знающего как C# так и actionSript. Что проще в изучении, перспективнее, проще в разработке. Какие подводные камни у этих платформ. Больше интересует сторона разработки 2d игр. Отдельно хотелось бы спросить, возможно ли на flash разрабатывать на box2d или др. физических движках и перенести это приложение без лишних танцев на iphone/android. Так же интересно, как выглядит установка flash игры на iphone/android проходит ли она без нареканий, или же требует установки плагинов, специфичного развертывания или каких либо других порогов для спокойного использование конечным пользователем? Так же интересно, хорошо ли потдерживается на этих платформах акселерометр? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите Corona. Уверен, человеку, который пишет на ActionScript-е не составит особого труда писать на Lua